# Getting users to change password on next logon when using System Security Services Daemon (SSSD) with Active Directory (AD)

Tags: linux, active-directory, rhel-6

We have a Active Directory (AD) setup with our Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) configured to use System Security Services Daemon (SSSD; non-LDAP) to authenticate users. We need to be able to force our AD users to require to change password upon next logon.

Currently when we run `chage -l username` we get a “user does not exist in /etc/passwd” error.

Any help would be appreciated, if this can even be done.

Comment: I do not understood: "do you have not installed at all `ldap`"? From [here](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Sssd) it seems needed. BTW maybe you can  find some hints in [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/691329/ldap-with-sssd-force-user-to-change-password-shadowlastchange-not-working)... (`pwdReset:TRUE` and on PPolicy's `pwdMustChange: TRUE`).

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I do not have a replica environment, this is just a suggestion.

First thing I'd test if the following works:

> At this point, you should be able to use the id $USER command to
>   lookup any user in Active Directory. In addition, the getent passwd
>   $USER command and getent group $GROUP command can be used to lookup
>   further user and group information in Active Directory.

If not, check out the third link for more direction troubleshooting.

Next to set all passwords to expire:

```
getent passwd|cut -d: -f1|xargs -n1 passwd -e
```

- http://thornelabs.net/2014/01/30/authenticate-rhel-5-and-6-against-active-directory-on-windows-server-2008-r2-with-sssd-using-kerberos-and-ldap.html
- http://www.lancaster.ac.uk/iss/tsg/unix-ad/